# Is the 6-sheeted covering of $S^1\vee S^1$ regular?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have a 6-sheeted covering $\widetilde{X_1}$ of $X:=S^1\vee S^1$. Is this covering regular/normal? Why? Here, the rotation by 180° around some $\tilde{x_i}$ for $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ represents a covering transformation for $\widetilde{X_1}$. But, I think it doesn't imply that for any $i,j\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ there exists a covering transformation sending $\tilde{x_i}$ to $\tilde{x_j}.$ Also, it seems difficult to study the image of the induced homomorphism in $\pi(X,x)$. Thanks!

[image: Is this covering regular?]

Comment: The rotations by 180° are not covering transformations, since they do not preserve the directions of the arrows. You get the covering transformations by sending $\tilde{x}_i$ to $\tilde{x}_{i+1}$ for all $i$, where the indices are understood modulo 6.

Comment: @D.Thomine: That looks like a good answer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the presentation $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)=\langle a,b\rangle$ with $a$ and $b$ corresponding to your edge labelings, there is a surjective homomorphism $f:\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)\to C_6$, where $C_6=\langle x\mid x^6=1\rangle$ is the cyclic group of order $6$, given by $a\mapsto x$ and $b\mapsto x$.  The $6$-sheeted covering space you draw is the one associated to $\ker(f)$.  Since kernels are normal subgroups, the cover is normal.

The covering transformations that D. Thomine mentions are from the action of $x$ on the cover, which shifts each $\widetilde{x}_i$ to $\widetilde{x}_{i+1}$ (with indices modulo $6$).

Comment: How do you conclude that the image $H$ of the induced homomorphism $p_{1*}:\pi_1(\widetilde{X_1})\to \pi(X)$ is equal to $ker(f)$?

Comment: @ErginSuer Notice $ab^{-1}$ is in the image and $a^6$ is in the image, as well as conjugates of these.  Also notice that $\langle a,b\mid ab^{-1},a^6\rangle$ is isomorphic to $C_6$.  This group has order $6$ and the covering space is $6$-sheeted, so by covering space theory, the $\ker(f)$ is the subgroup associated to your cover.  However, I went the other way: given such a map, you can draw the covering space associated to the kernel very directly, and the picture matches up with the one you drew.